# Preventing Jenkins from executing new builds in a defined time frame (e.g. 6-7am)

Tags: jenkins

Is there an elegant way to temporarily prevent Jenkins from executing any further builds in a defined time frame (say e.g. daily between 6am and 7am)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depening on what you want to achieve exactly you can probably use the [Exclusive Execution Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusive+Execution+Plugin). This plugin allows you to schedule a job which will block execution of all other jobs by putting Jenkins in shutdown mode (which is canceled when the job is done). You can make this job start at 6am and make ik run a simple ant script which sleeps for an hour.

However, if you are trying to use that window to e.g. run a backup you could actually run your backup from within that job, which will make 100% sure your backup won't start until all 
running jobs are completed and it will make Jenkins available again as soon as the backup is done.

Alternatively you could consider using cron or the windows scheduler (depending on your OS) to stop Jenkins completely at 6am and restart it at 7am.

Comment: Rather than stopping Jenkins, you can put it into "Quiet Down" mode, which prevents any new builds from taking place. You can enable this via the URLs `/quietDown` and `/cancelQuietDown`, or via the CLI commands `[cancel-]quiet-down`.

Comment: @christopher-orr THANKS! You should post your comment as an answer!

Comment: I like @ChristopherOrr's solution but could not make it work because of this old unresolved bug: [JENKINS-24958](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24958)

Comment: This solution does not work since jenkins will "freeze" pipeline jobs. if jenkisn is in quite-down mode new jobs will end in the queue BUT old builds pipeline jobs will not finish :/ I hope someone has an solution somwhen for this issue.

Answer (score 81):

Rather than stopping Jenkins, you can put it into "Quiet Down" mode, which prevents any new builds from taking place.

You can enable this via the URLs `/quietDown` and `/cancelQuietDown`, or via the [CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) commands `[cancel-]quiet-down`.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Thanks for this.

Comment: If you are using linux here are crons to do this
 
`00 07 * * * curl -X POST "http://$CI_HOSTNAME:$CI_PORT/jenkins/cancelQuietDown" >> ~/jenkins_logs/quiet.log`
    
`00 06 * * * curl -X POST "http://$CI_HOSTNAME:$CI_PORT/jenkins/quietDown" >> ~/jenkins_logs/quiet.log`

Comment: The solution does not work for pipeline jobs those will be frozen :/